# Notificações da fila de análise

Tags: suporte, status-intencional

Por que só quando há alguma Edição Sugerida na fila de análises que aparece aquele número do lado do link "análise"?

As outras análises como Primeiras Publicações, Respostas tardias, Votos para fechar, etc, nunca são notificadas com números (ao menos pra mim).

[image: ScreenShot da fila de análises]

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1284/7210

Comment: Vê essa resposta...

Comment: Uhmm, maluquice isso...

Comment: mas deixa ver o que diz o @Gabe

Comment: ou o @bfavaretto

Comment: No momento eu vejo 10 perguntas na fila de fechamento, 1 na de reabertura e o número está em 11. Tem como você conseguir um screenshot?

Comment: @Gabe coloquei um screen.

Comment: @Gabe a mim acontece-me o mesmo, as vezes tenho um monte de coisas para analisar e cadê a notificação com o número?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7wcMz9H.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O requisito para fila de análise mudou com a graduação. Agora é preciso ter 10 mil pontos para ter a notificação de todas as filas. Antes disso, como o Earendul percebeu, só aparece o contador da fila de edições sugeridas.

Além disso, é necessário ter pelo menos 3 itens para análise para que a notificação apareça.